# Why is this javascript ressetting the values for this rows in this 3d array every time I update it

Tags: javascript, algorithm

```
    const batchIndex = Math.floor(x / 30);
    const newX = x % 30;
    const innerMap = [...state.map[batchIndex][newX]];


    innerMap[newX] = thing;
    console.log(state.map[batchIndex]); // this shows the right value
    state.map[batchIndex] = [...state.map[batchIndex]];
    // This shows the previously right value reset to zero for some reason
    console.log(state.map[batchIndex]);


    state.map[batchIndex][z] = [...innerMap];
```

Anytime I add a row it clears out the previous rows. This doesn't happen for columns.

Comment: What is `z`, the same as `newX`?

Comment: Please show the complete code as a [mcve]

Comment: `innerMap[newX] = thing;` looks suspicious. The index `newX` was already used to *retrieve* `innerMap`, so is it really intended you use that same index on a *deeper* level?